# Copy file to folder if exist +1

Tags: php, copy

I'm new in php.
Every 17 seconds my php code generates id1.php and id2.php in this folder:"sitename.com/"
  So, every 17 seconds i've got this:

```
sitename.com/master.php
sitename.com/id1.php
sitename.com/id2.php
sitename.com/filebag/id1.php
sitename.com/filebag/id2.php
sitename.com/filebag/id3.php
```

after script generates id1.php and id2.php i need to copy this files to sitename/filebag/ and if filename exist add +1.  so in the end, i must get this situation:

```
sitename.com/
sitename.com/master.php
sitename.com/filebag/id1.php
sitename.com/filebag/id2.php
sitename.com/filebag/id3.php
sitename.com/filebag/id4.php
sitename.com/filebag/id5.php and so on...
```

i use master.php to do a replace

```
<?php 
$idname = "id1";
copy ("./id1.php","./filebag/$idname.php");
?>
```

question is how can i rename file if filename exist in this folder "sitename.com/filebag/"

Comment: maybe something like that?     <?php
$filename = '/filebag/$gotname.php';
$gotname = 'id$idnumber';
$idnumber = "1";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $idnumber+1;
} else {
   copy ("./doit.php","./filebag/$gotname.php");;
}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code delivers what you want:

```
<?php

$stringName = "id";
$numName = "1";

$file_orig = './' . $stringName . $numName . '.php'; 
$file_dest = './filebag/' . $stringName . $numName . '.php'; 

if(file_exists($file_dest))
{
   $count = (int)$numName;
   while(file_exists($file_dest))
   {
       $count = $count + 1;
       $file_dest = './filebag/' . $stringName . $count . '.php'; 
   }
}

copy ($file_orig, $file_dest);

?>
```

Comment: There is no problem with my code. The way you can get any problem is by setting the inputs wrongly; that is: you are setting a file/folder which does not exist. If both $file_orig and $file_dest refer to valid locations, it will work without any problem. Check this out, please.

Comment: Warning: copy($file_orig) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: ��� ������ ����� ��� �������� in /home/users/sitename.com/master.php on line 19
./id1.php

Comment: As said, there is a problem while intending to access any of these files. From this error message I understand that ./id1.php does not exist in your system.

Comment: You are welcome. I am really happy to make people happy so easily ;)